# Can I read the WiFi SSID, MAC Address, RSSI in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to read certain WiFi information such as the SSID, MAC address and RSSI (Signal Strength) in my Windows Phone 7 application programmatically.

If it's possible, how can I read this information on a HTC HD 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current SDK, you can't get any of that information. You can get the type of network the user is on via the [NetworkInformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707715%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), but nothing about the SSID/MAC/RSSI.

Comment: in win 6.5 SDK , i write a DLL C++ (win 6.5 SDK classes) that help me by invoking it from C# smart device application to get this information ... i really need help concerning this field

Comment: @user689851: Invoking unmanaged code via interop services is not allowedon Windows Phone 7. Even packaging an arbitrary DLL (without ever pinvoke'ing it) in the XAP file will cause your app to fail marketplace certification.

Comment: so what should i do in my project given this phone with this tools ? .. and i need to position a mobile terminal inside a building using Wifi indoors positioning system that depends on detecting signal strength from the nearest access point to this mobile terminal ????

Comment: @user689851 this is not going to be possible on WP7

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2011/08/30/finding-the-ssid-of-your-wi-fi-network-on-windows-phone-7-5-mango.aspx) and since still waiting for my Samsung Focus to confirm I asked mr Andy Pennell to comment if that is SSID or interface name (like wlan0, eth0... on linux) as per [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487166%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: You can read SSID, use [code from article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2011/08/30/finding-the-ssid-of-your-wi-fi-network-on-windows-phone-7-5-mango.aspx). I checked it on Samsung Focus and it returns nice looking SSID.