# WP 7.5 get MAC address

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've been stuck at this for some time. I SHOULD be really simple.
I want to read the MAC address of my WP7 device. It's a Nokia Lumia 800 running WP 7.5.

I can find the active network interface by doing:

```
var current = new NetworkInterfaceList().Current;
```

But how to I read the MAC address?

Comment: There is no public API for reading the MAC Address currently. What do you want it for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer vcsjones.
I'm building software for a payment provider and they track users via mac. However, I might be able to use DeviceUniqueId for the same purpose.

Comment: Oh, if you post an answer to this question I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I read the WiFi SSID, MAC Address, RSSI in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530125/can-i-read-the-wifi-ssid-mac-address-rssi-in-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vcsjones said in the comment, it's not possible in version 7.5.